# How to remove Docker proxy settings entirely?

Tags: docker, proxy

I have removed the files in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/` directory and restarted Docker with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart docker`. However, the proxy setting is never removed. The output of `sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker` is:

```
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8899 HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8899 NO_PROXY=0.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,100.64.0.0/10,127.0.0.0/8,169.254>
```

How can I entirely remove these proxy settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by editing `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`. Someone has set the environments in this file. After deleting these lines and restarting Docker, the proxy settings were removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! This answer save my precious time ..